# Thoughts on Open Logic Project?

Tags: logic, deduction, learning-methods

I'm currently thinking about starting to expand my knowledge of logic beyond what I retain from my previous study of logic by making use of the materials available through:
OpenLogicProject

(https://openlogicproject.org/)

I have read that it requires that I read at least a 'beginners' book on logic; therefore, I have started with Paul Teller's a Modern Formal Logic Primer.

Is the OpenLogicProject ("OLP") something I can progressively learn from without nail-biting and ear-pulling, having only read and completed a primer on modern formal logic? Has anyone else completed the entire document of the OLP and if so, did it provide the necessary depth to tackle more 'advanced' topics in logic? Also, does the majority of the material in OLP cover 'Philosophy of Logic', or 'Mathematical Logic'?

Comment: I **can't** truly vouch for its quality - it's gigantic and impossible to skim - but certainly [the people involved](https://openlogicproject.org/people/) are fantastic logicians. As to the content, it's definitely mathematical logic, although that's not to say that it's *irrelevant* for philosophical logic - indeed, I suspect that part of the motivation for it (it's specifically aimed at philosophers and computer scientists) is the belief that advanced pure mathematical logic is useful to philosophical and applied logic. I cannot say whether Teller's book is sufficient background for the OLP.

Comment: (The sheer amount of stuff I can't say is why that's a comment as opposed to an answer.)

Comment: OLP covers mathematical logic and is "aimed at a non-mathematical audience, intended for use in advanced logic courses as taught in many philosophy departments." That indicates it may be difficult to use on your own in self-directed study without the guidance of a professor. I know that many of the texts are intended as "lecture notes" that don't stand on their own without hearing a lecture.